# Prove equivalence regarding continuity

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, continuity

Let $f: R \to R$ be a function with $f(0) = -1$ and $f(x + y) \le -f(x)f(y) ~~~~\forall x, y\in R$.

Prove the following equivalence:

$f$ is continuous in $R \Leftrightarrow f$ is continuous in $0$

Thanks in advance, I really don't know where to start... Open for ideas to work with!

Comment: What is $f(x,y)$? $f$ is not defined on $\mathbb R^2$ but on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Please fix the question or it will get closed shortly.

Comment: I'm really sorry, it was meant to be summation... Edited it!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ continuous at zero.

Then for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $h$.

$f(x+h) \leq - f(x)f(h) \to f(x)$.
$f(x-h+h) \leq -f(x+h)f(h) \to f(x+h)$.

Hence $f(x) \leq \lim_{h \to 0}f(x+h) \leq f(x)$. 
Since $h$ was arbitrary, this limit exists on either side.

Hence $f$ cts as $x$.

The other direction is tautology.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the first part of the solution. How did we conclude that $f(x) \le \lim_{h \to 0}f(x + h) \le f(x)$?

Comment: we ued the inequality with $y= h$ and took the limit as $h \to 0$ of both sides of the equation, noting that the inequality still stands.

Comment: I still can't really get the way it was written. Sorry if I'm being a little bit too slow on that one, but I just can't see through the connection. Could you provide juast a tiny bit more detail, if it's no problem to you? Thank you a lot, really!

Comment: yeah no problem. 
Inequality 1:
$f(x+h)\leq -f(x)f(h)$. That's using the inequality given. Now we take the limit of $h\to 0$, noting that $f(0)=-1$.

This tells us that the limit $\lim f(x+h) \leq f(x)$

Comment: I got that, but how did we obtain $f(x) \le lim_{h \to 0}f(x + h)$?